# Xcode 4 and VST MODULE ARCHITECTURE SDK

Tags: xcode, midi, vst

Does somebody know about Xcode and Steinbergs VST MODULE ARCHITECTURE SDK?

In their SDK which you can download here
http://www.steinberg.net/nc/de/company/developer/sdk_download_portal/vst_module_architecture_sdk.html
they included a Xcode example which I cant open, because its an old pbproj file.

I tried to setup a new project by myself but I cant get it to work : (

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a tutorial about this awhile back:

- [Making a VST plugin from scratch with Xcode](http://www.teragonaudio.com/2010/06/making-vst-plugin-from-scratch-with.html)

The instructions are written for Xcode 3, but it should also work for Xcode 4. If you notice any major discrepancies, let me know and I'll make an updated version.